# Checking username and password on every app opens

Tags: android

I am building an app,users can login to system.But I am confused about this.When user logins to app i am storing his/her username and password in app database (crypted) and every app opens i am sending this username and password to server for check.Is this a good approach ? If not,how should be ?

Comment: Consider implementing something like OAuth on your server. Then you could store the token on your device, rather than the user credentials.

Comment: On every app opens,should i check token with server ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing a password, even encrypted, client side is not a good idea.  First off, passwords should never be stored, they should be salted and hashed and the result stored, so if the storage is compromised its impossible to get the password.  Secondly, where is the encryption key coming from?  If its in the app, its trivial to reverse engineer and unencrypt.  That's why you don't store it, you send it to the server once and use an access token-  see xaevinx suggestion of OAuth for an implementation.

Comment: Ok,i will use access token.But should i check this token on every app opens ?

Comment: Anytime you need to ensure that its the user.  Which should be anytime API call that provides private information and before accessing any local private information.

Comment: I see but this is a chat app,so user can be send message to others without provide information

Comment: Add "whenever an API call is made that sends data the server needs to trust".  Such as sending chat text to the server.  If you don't authenticate when that happens, then you're open for rather simple identity theft hacks.  Unless you're dropping down to the socket level and keeping an open connection-  in that case you only need to authenticate when the connection is first opened, the continued connection itself is your authentication.